# How to create a control Slider with 2 check?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I would try to create a user control in a windows app. I tried to enter this code:

```
public double Minimum
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(MinimumProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MinimumProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MinimumProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Minimum", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));

public double LowerValue
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(LowerValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(LowerValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty LowerValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("LowerValue", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));

public double UpperValue
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(UpperValueProperty); }
    set { SetValue(UpperValueProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty UpperValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("UpperValue", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(0d));

public double Maximum
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(MaximumProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MaximumProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MaximumProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Maximum", typeof(double), typeof(RangeSlider), new UIPropertyMetadata(1d));
```

Then I plugged in xaml control so:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="Doppio_Cursore.MyUserControl1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Doppio_Cursore"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    d:DesignWidth="400"
    x:name= "root">

    <Grid>
        <Slider x:Name="LowerSlider"
        Minimum="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Minimum}"
        Maximum="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Maximum}"
        Value="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=LowerValue}" />

        <Slider x:Name="UpperSlider"
        Minimum="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Minimum}"
        Maximum="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=Maximum}"
        Value="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=UpperValue}" />

    </Grid>

</UserControl>
```

I believe that with this code if I'm not mistaken, I should see a slider-slider, no?
 Instead I get a simple slider with a single slider. Where am I wrong?

Comment: I think the reason is that one is rendered on top of the other one.  Try putting each slider into its own row in the grid, or use a FlowLayoutPanel with the orientation set to vertical.

Comment: I have two Slider, but each with a single slider

Comment: Are you trying to create a single slider with two thumbs? If so, I found this:  http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/626132/WPF-MultiRangeSlider-Control

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to do this but I can not.

Comment: I was following this guide, although this is also for wpf, and I program for Windows app, but I do not work the same..http://www.thejoyofcode.com/Creating_a_Range_Slider_in_WPF_and_other_cool_tips_and_tricks_for_UserControls_.aspx